# Trouble passing props to componentDidMount in child component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues passing a prop to a `componentDidMount()` call in a child component on my `React` application.

In my `App.js` I am passing props via `Router` like below:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    city: ""
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({city: this.props.city});
}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Route path="/" exact render = {() => <Projections city={this.state.city} />} />
            <Route path="/:id" component={FullPage} />
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

In my **Projections.js** I have the following:

**Projections.js**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
           this.state = {
            location: this.props.city
        }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        console.log(this.state.location);
console.log(this.props.city);

    }
```

`console.log(this.state);' returns an empty string.`console.log(this.props.city);` returns an empty string as well.

But I need to access the value of the `city` prop within `componentDidMount()`. `console.log(this.props.city);` within `render()` returns the prop, but not in `componentDidMount()`

Why is this and how do I return `props` within `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: You say that the first console.log returns an empty string, then the second one return nothing **as well**. An empty string is not nothing ;) Especially when you do `state = {
    city: ""
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <Route path="/" exact render = {() => <Projections city={this.state.city} {...this.props} />} />
```

Try **passing rest of props in route**

this is because you assigned props in `constructor` that time it may or may not receive actual value. And it gets called only once in a component lifecycle.
You can use `componentWillReceiveProps` to get props whenever it receive and update state accordingly.

Inside  **Projections.js**

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(nextProps.city){
     this.setState({location:nextProps.city})
   }
}
```

Here is working [codesand](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrrzvvn05q)

Comment: thank you but I still got the same result for `state` it returns an empty string.

Comment: So this exact solution doesn’t work but it led me to my solution that I did end up getting to work, I will post it soon

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor you should reference `props`, not `this.props`:

```
location: props.city
```

Comment: Thank you but that still returned null on the console.log

Comment: @logos_164 which line returned `null`? Are you sure that the value returned is `null`? In JavaScript, `null`, `undefined` and `''` are not the same thing.

Comment: when I `console.log(this.state.location)` within `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Is `this.props.city` defined in `App.js`? If not, it would override the empty string you set in the constructor.

Comment: Yes it is it's passed from `index.js`

Comment: @logos_164 so you see `null`? Because in JavaScript, it's quite uncommon to get `null` without setting it yourself. You sure you show the whole code? That's quite weird. I could imagine you would get `undefined`, but here, i cannot understand how you get `null`.

Comment: @sjahan yes my apologies, the Chrome console returns nothing on that line, so it is an empty string

Comment: It would make sense for those to be empty strings, since that's how they're defined. Try passing `App.js` a non-empty `city` prop

Comment: @AlanFriedman yes I've done that, when you `console.log(this.props.city)` within `render()` it returns the value of the prop

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't pass into `componentDidMount()` the `console.log(this.props.city)` returns an empty string, but in render it returns the value.

Comment: It's probably because `componentDidMount` is called before the new parent state is set. Try moving the loggers into `componentWillReceiveProps`.